# Проверка на то в каком чате отрабатывать

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
def del_all_links(chat_id, ban_time):
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id == chat_id)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id, message.from_user.id, until_date=time() + ban_time)
            bot.delete_message(chat_id, message.message_id)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, f"В данной группе ссылки запрещены"
                                      f"\nБлокировка чата на 2 минут для пользователя, "
                                      f"{message.from_user.first_name}!")
        else:
            return
```

кто то может подсказать в чем проблема, не отрабатывает проверка  (message.chat.id == chat_id)
если эту проверку не использовать то бот отрабатывает некоректно в разных группах

Comment: Для начала ставьте скобки в условиях.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Интересно зачем?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Чтобы самому не гадать, и не попадать в просак, пример(php):
 `$a=$c==$d?$e==$f?$g:$h==$i?1:0;` расставите скобки как это сделает php?

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Питон — не php. Условия в нем гораздо читаемeй (как и все остальное). В примере кода из вопроса скобки не нужны.

Comment: нашёл решение ) нужно использовать не chat_id а message.chat.id в bot.restrict_chat_member и тогда проверка не нужна ) правда странно что она не работает )

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica согласен что питон не пхп, но это не отменяет того факта что со скобками - быстрее и проще понять как именно ведется обработка условий(в каком порядке), и это не зависит от ЯП. т.е. условие со скобками сможет понять любой программист, даже если он не знает особенностей ЯП(пример - тернарники в пхп).

Comment: @Владимир Клыков В вопросе одиночные условия — порядка нет вообще. Питонисту и так легко. Скобки в условиях — плохой code-style.

Comment: `Скобки в условиях — плохой code-style.` Много раз слышал обратное, и сам такого придерживаюсь =) Возможно для конкретных ЯП это и плохая практика, но не для всех. **Иногда** без скобок - невозможно записать условие верно.